# Are electrical subpanels safe in the bedroom?

Tags: electrical, safety, code-compliance

If not, how do you correct it, or can it be moved without making too much work?

Answer (score 3):

It should be safe as long as you maintain the required minimum distances to flammable materials and don't obstruct access to the panel. That means you can't cover the panel or have it near any wall hangings, curtains, bedding, etc.

You also must keep access to it, which means it shouldn't be behind furniture or inaccessible for some other reason.

As for moving it, that would be a lot of work. It would require rewiring all the circuits that go to that panel, and also rerunning the cable that runs from the subpanel back to your main service panel.

Answer (score 0):

NEC doesn't mention anything that would prohibit electrical panels in a bedroom. I would still probably have my bed on the opposite wall, just in case. So it's definitely legal.
As for moving it - it might be doable, but most likely will be impractical. Every single branch circuit from this panel would have to rerouted to a new location which will require quite a bit of wall opening.

Comment: My ~40 year old apartment is wired with my panel in the bedroom.  It's on an otherwise unusable section of wall in the space where the main and closet doors swing when open.